# How to prepend the CDN url to requirejs paths in a build script

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, requirejs

given this `requirejs` config:

```
require.config({
  baseUrl: './js',
  paths: {
    'jquery': 'vendor/jquery',
    'bootstrap': 'vendor/bootstrap',
    'basicModel': 'app/models/basicModel',
    'aboutModel': 'app/models/aboutModel',
    'contactModel': 'app/models/contactModel',
    'models': 'models',
    'vendor': 'vendor'
  },
  shim: {
    'bootstrap': ['jquery', 'models']
  }
});
```

I would like my automation script that prepares a package for production to map each of the values inside the `paths` object as the following:

```
'jquery': [cdnUrl + 'vendor/jquery', 'vendor/jquery'],
```

As you can see, the `cdnUrl` is an actual variable that will hold my CDN endpoint on runtime. The endpoint cannot be determined on build time, when this script should run.

How can I make this kind of mapping?

EDIT:

I do not want to use regex in this case, as my real `require.config.js` file is larger and more complicated due to having more properties other than `paths` that have the same syntax.

I have a script that parses the above config using `requirejs-config-file` npm package and basically turns this to a real object. I just can't figure out if what I'm asking is possible in javascript code (not text editing).

Comment: You want something like `paths['jquery'] = [cdnUrl + paths['jquery'], paths['jquery']]`?

Comment: yes. how can this be achieved?

Comment: The title on this question is really unclear; I don't see what this has to do with variable names and values or mapping.

Comment: well, I would like to map some value to include some other variable name.
I can edit the topic if you have a better suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
var config = {
      baseUrl: './js',
      paths: {
            'jquery': 'vendor/jquery',
            'bootstrap': 'vendor/bootstrap',
            'basicModel': 'app/models/basicModel',
            'aboutModel': 'app/models/aboutModel',
            'contactModel': 'app/models/contactModel',
            'models': 'models',
            'vendor': 'vendor'
      },
      shim: {
            'bootstrap': ['jquery', 'models']
      }
};

for(var path in config.paths){
    var pathValue = config.paths[path];
    config.paths[path] = [cdnUrl + pathValue, pathValue];
}
console.log(config.paths);
```

Comment: this won't work as `cdnUrl` will be evaluated. I only know its value on runtime, not on build time.

Comment: Maybe an http call for the value, or maybe reading it from another source? Maybe a function that works with promises to update the values when `cdnUrl` is ready

Comment: if I could have the final value be exactly like this: `'jquery': [cdnUrl + 'vendor/jquery', 'vendor/jquery'],` - that would work. but as I'm giving it more thoughts it looks impossible.